# Alerts for tableview cells

Tags: uiview, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, uialertview

How can we create alerts for cells in tableviews.What are the methods used to implement them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alerts? You need to be more specific. If you are talking about `UIAlertView`, you can do it like this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UIAlertView *alert =
    [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: aTitle
                               message: @"My message"
                              delegate: self
                     cancelButtonTitle: @"OK"
                     otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];

}
```

You are showing an alert when you click a cell. Also notice that you are setting that alertView's delegate as self. So, your class needs to comply with the `UIAlerViewDelegate`, if you want to add some logic after the user selects a button.